# Remove auto suggestion for usernames

Tags: macos

[image]

How do I remove this function?

Answer (score 1):

It's up to the website to disable autocorrect on fields. You can disable autocorrect globally: go to System Preferences → Keyboard → Text and uncheck ‘Correct spelling automatically’.

Instead of disabling it, you can click the × to cancel that correction, and once you've done that a few times, the word will be added to the dictionary and won't be autocorrected.